# Eclipse plugin templates don't work after export

Tags: eclipse, templates

I have made a template plugin that adds new plugin project templates to Eclipse. in my workspace everything seems to work fine, but when I export the bundle to an export folder, or an update site, the templates don't work correctly. I have seen that both the icons that you can add to the extensions, as well as the files in the  templates_xxx directory don't seem to be processed, so I thought it might be a build.properties problem, but when I included them (and verified that these are actually bundled in the jars) the behaviour seems the same.

Has anyone had similar experiences, and solved it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out what was wrong. During development the 'Imported Packages' list of my Manifest.MF had become cluttered. as a result, it was almost impossible for the bundle to start in another target, with the above behaviour as a result.

Lessons learned:

- Always look for unused dependencies' (dependency analysis in the depndencies tab of the Manifest editor) and remove them
- The problem will show itself by icons added for extensions that are not displayed in the production environment